# Improper definite integral

Tags: calculus

Could someone help me with this integral. I stumbled across this as a homework problem but I don't seem to be able to integrate it. 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+ {x}^{2})}{1+ {x}^{2}}dx$$

Answer (score 6):

Hint 1: Let $x=\tan \theta$

Hint 2:
For evaluating the new integral, remember that $$\int^a_0f(x)\,dx=\int^a_0f(a-x)\,dx$$